# MongoDB Command Line Tool

Tags: windows-7, database-administration, mongodb

Is it possible to enter arbitrary command in MongoVUE and get result?  If there is not such feature do you know any other windows app that can be used as mongo front-end console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Robomongo — is a shell-centric cross-platform open source MongoDB
>   management tool (i.e. Admin GUI). Robomongo embeds the same JavaScript
>   engine that powers MongoDB's mongo shell. Everything you can write in
>   mongo shell — you can write in Robomongo!

http://robomongo.org/